# API URL Structure

Tags: api, rest

I'm creating a sweepstakes application that is powered by an API. The hierarchy is fairly straightforward.

1. Clients
2. Users
3. Sweepstakes
4. Submissions

Clients can have users who are essentially admins of any sweepstakes. Clients can also have multiple sweepstakes. And a single sweepstakes can have multiple submissions. Okay, not complicated.

Where I get confused is what the correct approach is towards the URL structure. I've read documentation and best practice blogs all over the internet, and yet I'm still confused. Here are our current routes:

***CLIENTS***

**POST** /clients
**GET** /clients
**GET** /clients/:client_id
**PUT** /clients:client_id

***USERS***

**POST** /users
**GET** /users
**GET** /users/:user_id
**PUT** /users/:user_id
**DELETE** /users/:user_id

***SWEEPSTAKES***

**POST** /sweepstakes
**GET** /sweepstakes
**GET** /sweepstakes/:sweepstakes_id
**PUT** /sweepstakes/:sweepstakes_id
**DELETE** /sweepstakes/:sweepstakes_id

***SUBMISSIONS***

**POST** /submissions
**GET** /submissions
**GET** /submissions/:submission_id
**PUT** /submissions/:submission_id
**DELETE** /submissions/:submission_id

As you can see, I'm following a simple 2 URLs per resource -- what I feel is best practice. You can then drill into associations via query parameters on any GET request (e.g. **/submissions?sweepstakes_id={sweepstakes_id}**, **/sweepstakes?client_id={client_id}**, etc.).

This of course makes sense to me, however my co-worker and I are in a tiff because he is using Backbone to build the primary front-end app. Backbone states that they support RESTful API consumption off the bat, but my co-worker is telling me that Backbone prefers a URL structure that represents that hierarchal structure. I of course think that will leads to a messy, long, and overall confusing URL structure. Ideally, my co-worker would like to see the following URL structures:

**GET** /clients
**GET** /clients/users
**GET** /clients/sweepstakes
**GET** /clients/sweepstakes/submissions

Note: the above routes would also have additional routes to compliment single resources via an additional resource id in the URL (e.g. **/clients/users/:user_id**, **/clients/sweepstakes/:sweepstakes_id/submissions**, etc.).

I know this is somewhat of a touchy subject, but I'd love to hear some feedback on this. I vote for one 2 URLs per resource, and if any associations need to be made, they can be done so through the use of GET, or POST parameters. But I could be totally wrong.

Comment: Not a good question. like you said, it's a touchy subject. there's no right/wrong answer.

Comment: @Marc B I'm simply asking for feedback / suggestions. Not what is right or wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, this is a controversial topic.  That being said I've found the gang at [Apigee](http://apigee.com) to be very helpful when trying to flesh out api standards/definition.  They do not say that one way is correct, they more lean towards educated recommendations based off of their industry experience.

They offer some great resources and have some content that may help you get to a position where you can defend your opinion with someone else in your corner.

Check out this [webinar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8SIxZVaai4&feature=BFa&list=PL3E6A77048ED2E29F&lf=plcp)... it is fairly basic stuff but always great for a refresher when it comes to api design.

note: I have no affiliation with Apigee, I just think that they have done some great work trying to get a standard defined for api design.

~ good luck and I hope this helps

Comment: This was published just a couple weeks later (Nov 2011 instead of Sep 2011), but it's the "second edition" version of that same webinar.  I have yet to watch either, so I can't say with experience yet https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpAhXa12xvU

Answer (score 1):

I can't find anything in the [official definition of REST](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) that suggests that hierarchical URIs are preferred, but I may have missed something. I don't know anything about Backbone, but if it needs that structure I guess you have to do it, but there does not appear to be any reason why it would be better outside of that. However it is often preferred that each resource have one unique URI and the hierarchical one appears to have several. I know that you can't speak for your workmate, but has he offered any tangible reason why his scheme would have better functionality?